# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: 234

Tags: jquery

I want to run a post where I am returned with some data from the server. I received the area from the Chrome console report. Now, 234 is what I want to be returned and I assume that the ajax_file.php does work because it is returning the 234, but I am getting the error. What is wrong with my code?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#button_id').click(function() {
    var search_term = $('#search_term').val();
    $.post('ajax_file.php', {search_term: search_term}, function (data) {
        $(data).appendTo('#div_tag');
    });
});

</script>           

<div id="div_tag"></div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you pass `data` to `jQuery`, it is interpreted as **selector** and the value `234` is an invalid selector.

Instead of passing the response to `jQuery`, reverse the operands and use [`.append` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/append/):

```
$('#div_tag').append(data);
```

---

Although it is possible to [pass an HTML string to `jQuery`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2), your string does not contain any HTML (tags) and therefore jQuery does not know that you want it to be interpreted as such.